# PHPSpreadsheet: how to get the number of loaded rows?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

How do I find out how many rows I have loaded using `PHPSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx::load()` method?

I cannot find methods (or properties) for getting row count in Spreadsheet or Worksheet classes either.

BTW I am using following code:

```
$filename = 'test.xlsx';
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($filename);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);  
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheet);  

$this->spreadsheet = $reader->load($filename);
$this->worksheet = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using the worksheet's `getHighestRow()` method

```
$highestRow = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
```

or `getHighestDataRow()` if you're only interested in rows where cells contain data and not any blank rows at the end of the worksheet

Comment: to be noted: for columns, they have a similarly but not very intuitively named method `getHighestColumn`

Comment: this gives column index e.g AJ what about count?

Comment: @NixonKosgei - then use the Coordinate columnIndexFromString() method to convert AJ to its numeric equivalent